# Urls /lpt1 and /com1 cause IIS to render its own screen of death

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

When running a recent SkipFish scan - we found that IIS (7.5) returns the following if you call `/lptX` or `/comX` (where X is a number 1-9).

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you ...[and so on]...
```

This is dispite the fact that we have custom [pretty] errors at the site-level and at the web server config level.

Try it on your IIS box now if you have one - http://localhost/lpt1 should do it.

I'm guessing this is a legacy thing from 'the good ol days' of LPT printers and mice connecting via COM ports. But it is slightly unsettling to see and area of IIS that I can't config.

**Is it possible to force IIS to serve a custom 404 page even for these 'special' URLs?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until ASP.NET 4.0 it wasn't possible to use certain reserved filenames such as `con`, `lpt`, `aux` and so in on your urls:

> [Zombie Operating Systems and ASP.NET MVC](http://bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/)

This was a limitation of ASP.NET, not MVC.

However the good news is that it's now possible:

> [Putting the Con (COM1, LPT1, NUL, etc.) Back in your URLs](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx)

If you're not using ASP.NET 4.0, you should be able to catch these 404's using IIS7's own [`<httpErrors>`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors) configuration settings.

Comment: Can you add an example of how to use <httpErrors> to handle this kind of error? I tried but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

With ASP .NET 3.5 you can use an url rewrite rule of the url rewrite module in order to change the url to a valid one.

The [url rewite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) is:

> The Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 and above enables IIS
>   administrators to create powerful customized rules to map request URLs
>   to friendly URLs that are easier for users to remember and easier for
>   search engines to find

Something like:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CON rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/(con\.)(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/con-{R:3}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>     
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```