# How to display custom error page when URL is /AUX and relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping is false

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I enter /AUX in url (or any other url mentioned here: https://www.itnews.com.au/news/how-a-1974-bug-still-bites-win10-and-azure-users-515102)
I get ugly 404 page.

I know that I can set `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to `true`, but I don't want to do that.

What I want is just to display nice error page in that case. Is it possibel?

I tried `httpErros` and `customErros` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the problme somehow the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6455135/4636715 ?

Comment: Yes and no. There is info that I can use <httpErrors> but I tried it and <customErros> and it didn't work for me.